# Implement a relation using db4o

Tags: java, db4o

For testing purposes i want to implement a relationship between two java classes for instance student and exam. How can i make relationships using db4o. I don't have much experience with this DB - system, just worked with hibernate so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

db4o is a object oriented database so all you need to do is to define a field in **Exam** class that references **Student**.

For instance?

```
class Exam
{
   List<Student> students;
}
```

This way whenever you save / retrieve an **Exam** instance **db4o** will take care of retrieving the students (there are some limits related to how *deep* **db4o** will follow the rabbit hole, i.e, how many levels of reference will **db4o** load but you can control this and in general the default configuration  has a good compromise regarding *usage easiness* / *memory consumption* / *performance*